# How do I use cljsjs packages in a deps.edn project

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, deps-edn, cljsjs

I've tried adding a dependency to my deps.edn:

```
{:deps {cljsjs/js-yaml   {:mvn/version "3.3.1-0"}
       ...}
```

But I'm not able to call functions from that library.

In the REPL:

```
cljs.user=> (require '[cljsjs.js-yaml])
cljs.user=> js/safeLoad
Execution error (ReferenceError) at (<cljs repl>:1).
safeLoad is not defined
```

The [instructions](https://github.com/cljsjs/packages/wiki/Using-Packages) I found are for leinigen (project.clj). Do I need to do something special to get it working in deps.edn?

Comment: You use `(:require ...)` which is just a keyword lookup when used outside the `ns` form. You need `(require '[...])`. Not sure cljsjs can be required at the REPL like this though, but there is no difference in including it via `deps.edn` or `project.clj`.

Comment: Oh, thank you, that was a typo. I still get the same output after removing `:`. Question updated.
Also, I do get an `#object` when I try another library in the REPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do js/jsyaml.safeLoad and at the repl you need to use the function `require` rather than the symbol used in a ns declaration.

```
bfabry@18723-bfabry /t/foo> plk
ClojureScript 1.10.520
cljs.user=> (require '[cljsjs.js-yaml])
nil
cljs.user=> (js/jsyaml.safeLoad "app:\n  bar: baz\n")
#js {:app #js {:bar "baz"}}
cljs.user=>
```

the packages are namespaced using js objects of their own name.